# Run a django command for a set duration inside of a test

Tags: python, django, pytest, python-multithreading, pytest-django

**Update 4/21/23**

Below is the working test thanks to [Paul Gilmartin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11019861/paul-gilmartin) answer (creator of [django-pgpubsub](https://github.com/Opus10/django-pgpubsub)). I renamed my Notification model in the import to EmailNotification to reduce confusion as it's the same name as the Notification model in django-pgpubsub:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)  # needed to work
def test_shipment_status_notificiations(testuser, pg_connection):
    user = testuser
    # should already be made by our signal
    notification_settings = NotificationSettings.objects.get(user=user)
    notification_settings.failed_delivery_attempt = True
    notification_settings.available_for_pickup = True
    notification_settings.delivery_issue = True
    notification_settings.save()
    cust_email = "test@tester.com"
    customer = Customer.objects.create(email=cust_email)
    order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)
    shipment = Shipment.objects.create(user=user, order=order)
    pg_connection.poll()
    shipment.status = Shipment.FAILED_ATTEMPT
    shipment.save()
    shipment.status = Shipment.HELD
    shipment.save()
    shipment.status = Shipment.ISSUE
    shipment.save()
    assert 3 == len(pg_connection.notifies)

    # process_notifications() is needed for the listener to run and EmailNotifications to be created
    process_notifications(pg_connection)
    print(f"all emailnotifications: {EmailNotification.objects.all()}")
    existing_notifications = EmailNotification.objects.filter(
        shipment=shipment,
        email=cust_email,
    )
    assert existing_notifications.count() == 3
```

**Original Post Sections Below (now outdated)**

**Problem**

I have a test that runs a django-admin command in a thread with a timeout. The test passes, but it hangs and I must manually stop its execution. I'm not familiar with threading, but I think the thread keeps running, which causes the test to "hang" after it passes. I'm looking for a solution that runs the command since this is more of an integration test and not a unit test with mocks. Any solution that runs the command for a set duration should work as long as there's proper test teardown and it doesn't cause issues for other tests during CI.

**Background**

[Django-pgpubsub](https://github.com/Opus10/django-pgpubsub) listens for PostgresSQL triggers by running
`python manage.py listen`. I'm using this as a lightweight alternative to Django signals and celery for sending emails when a Shipment model instance's status field changes to specific values.

**The Test**

```
# transaction=True is needed listen command to work for django-pgpubsub
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_shipment_status_notifications_with_listen_command(testuser):
    user = testuser
    notification_settings = NotificationSettings.objects.get(user=user)
    notification_settings.failed_attempt = True
    notification_settings.save()
    cust_email = "test@somedomain.com"
    customer = Customer.objects.create(email=cust_email)
    order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)

    def run_listen_command():
        call_command("listen")

    listen_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_listen_command, daemon=True)
    listen_thread.start()
    # Change Shipment status to trigger the notification
    shipment = Shipment.objects.create(user=user, order=order)
    shipment.status = Shipment.FAILED_ATTEMPT
    shipment.save()
    sleep(1)  # required to allow listen command to process the notification
    # Ensure the function that sends the notification is called and the notification is created
    existing_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(
        type=Notification.Type.FAILED_DELIVERY_ATTEMPT,
        shipment=shipment,
        email=cust_email,
    )
    assert existing_notifications.count() == 1
    # Wait for the listen_thread to complete, with a timeout
    # todo: this doesn't end the test and it hangs
    listen_thread.join(timeout=3)
```

**Other Attempts**

I'm unable to customize the Django command because it's from an external library, [django-pgpubsub](https://github.com/Opus10/django-pgpubsub). I'm unsure if threading is the best solution since I found this suggestion using GPT-4 and was unable to find existing examples. Another attempt involved a ThreadPoolExecutor with a try/except/finally with a TimeoutError. This also passed but hung. Another involved using the subprocess module. This version fails since no notifications are sent, or it hangs if subprocess.PIPE is passed to the stdout and stderr  parameters of subprocess.Popen() for troubleshooting. Here's the code for this version of the test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_shipment_status_notifications_with_listen_command_subprocess(testuser):
    print("starting test")
    user = testuser
    notification_settings = NotificationSettings.objects.get(user=user)
    notification_settings.failed_attempt = True
    notification_settings.save()
    cust_email = "test@somedomain.com"
    customer = Customer.objects.create(email=cust_email)
    order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)

    print(f"settings.ROOT_DIR: {settings.ROOT_DIR}")
    listen_command = [
        "python",
        str(settings.ROOT_DIR / "manage.py"),
        "listen",
    ]
    print("about to call listen command: ", listen_command)

    # todo: this version doesn't hang the test, but no notifications are sent
    # listen_process = subprocess.Popen(listen_command)
    # todo: using this version with stdout and stderr hangs the test
    listen_process = subprocess.Popen(listen_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True)
    # Change Shipment status to trigger the notification
    shipment = Shipment.objects.create(user=user, order=order)
    shipment.status = Shipment.FAILED_ATTEMPT
    shipment.save()

    time.sleep(5)

    # Stop the listen command
    listen_process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
    listen_process.wait()

    stdout, stderr = listen_process.communicate()

    print("Output from listen command:")
    print(stdout)
    print("Error output from listen command:")
    print(stderr)

    existing_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(
        type=Notification.Type.FAILED_DELIVERY_ATTEMPT,
        shipment=shipment,
        email=cust_email,
    )
    # todo: No existing notifications found when using listen_process = subprocess.Popen(listen_command)
    print(f"existing_notifications: {existing_notifications}")
    assert existing_notifications.count() == 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of django-pgpubsub. Great to see your interest in the library!

This isn't strictly an answer, but I don't have enough karma to leave a comment. I don't 100% understand what you want to do with the test, but it seems like you want to simulate what happens when the `listen` process is running in order to consume Notification objects?

You don't necessarily need to use the `listen` management command here, nor run it in a separate process to do this. Instead, you can use the `pgpubsub.listen.listen` function directly in the same thread as the test and then use the `poll` function on the db connection. https://github.com/Opus10/django-pgpubsub/blob/master/pgpubsub/tests/test_core.py has a few examples of tests doing this, in particular

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_recover_notifications(pg_connection):
    Author.objects.create(name='Billy')
    Author.objects.create(name='Billy2')
    pg_connection.poll()
    assert 2 == len(pg_connection.notifies)
    assert 2 == Notification.objects.count()
    assert 0 == Post.objects.count()
    # Simulate when the listener fails to
    # receive notifications
    pg_connection.notifies = []
    pg_connection.poll()
    assert 0 == len(pg_connection.notifies)
    listen(recover=True, poll_count=1)
    pg_connection.poll()
    assert 0 == Notification.objects.count()
    assert 2 == Post.objects.count()
```

You probably don't need to pass in `recover=False` for your case. There are also tests in that module using `process_notifications`, which is a function used internally in `listen`.

Maybe I should add some docs on unit testing!

Comment: Thanks for the help and for making this great library. It boggles my mind why there aren't more users, given that it's much more efficient and less problematic than running celery.
I had to use process_notifications to get my listener function (in listeners.py) to run.

Comment: @NathanSmeltzer You're welcome! Yeah hopefully more users will come eventually, it's just quite hard to publicise these things. Feel free to reach out if you have more questions or suggestions for the library.

Answer (score 0):

My application has management commands that run as background tasks on the server. I let them run for 60 minutes, then they finish and get re-started. The duration in minutes is a command line argument.

For testing, I have added the option `--quick`, which changes the duration to seconds.

Management command skeleton:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import datetime

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def __init__(self, stdout=None, stderr=None, no_color=False, force_color=False):
        super().__init__(stdout, stderr, no_color, force_color)
        self.stop_at = datetime.datetime.now()

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('duration', type=int,
                            choices={1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 60})
        parser.add_argument('--quick', action='store_true')     # for testing

    def _set_stop_time(self, **options):
        # decide when to stop running
        duration = options['duration']

        if options['quick']:
            self.stop_at += datetime.timedelta(seconds=duration)
        else:
            self.stop_at += datetime.timedelta(minutes=duration)

        self.stdout.write('[INFO] Will run until %s' % str(self.stop_at))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self._set_stop_time(**options)
        # ...
```

Unit test using the `--quick` option:

```
from django.core import management
from django.test import TestCase

class Foo(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        f1 = io.StringIO()
        f2 = io.StringIO()
        management.call_command('mgmt_cmd', '1', '--quick', stderr=f1, stdout=f2)
        #self.assert...
```